# Javascript pass value from popup page to parent

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I have a parent page that opens a popup page. on the popup page the user can select a value which is passed back to the parent page.

The code snippet on the parent page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function selectValue(id) 
{ 
    // open popup window and pass field id 
    window.open('sku.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(id),'popuppage', 
      'width=400,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=400,top=100,left=100'); 
} 

function updateValue(id, value) 
{ 
    // this gets called from the popup window and updates the field with a new value 
    document.getElementById(id).value = value; 
} 

</script>
```

and the code snippet for tha popup age is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function sendValue(value) 
{ 
    var parentId = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['id']); ?>; 
    window.opener.updateValue(parentId, value); 
    window.close(); 
} 
</script>
```

I need to change the popup page code so that the user can select a category which takes them to another page(Still in the popup page). Now when in this page they select the value, it is not passed back to the parent page as the parent page has changed.

Ho can I edit the popup code to point back to the original parent page? in my case the parent page is newsalea.php. Can I do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function sendValue(value) 
{ 
    var parentId = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['id']); ?>; 
    window.opener.updateValue(newsale.php, value); 
    window.close(); 
}
```

This way I hardcode the parentid into the popup pages? is this possible?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Does it have to be a new window. Could you use a modal div?

Comment: Yeah, don't use popup windows. They are horrible UX and usually profoundly annoying.

Comment: Hi Dave, yip it has to be a new page as the parent has over 150 rows on it so cant get the div to appear in the correct place for user to select an option. Thanks,

Comment: @ThiefMaster, unfortunately I have to use the popup on this one. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use window.open you can use popup javascript libraries like [jquery dialoge](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)! or [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)  and simply say parent.div=your value